# socket programming using node js in Hyperledger fabrics chaincode

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to use socket programming inside the hyperledger fabric network for sending the message from one person to another. 
is it possible?

Is it possible to send messages from one organization admin like money details to another organization admin and he sends the (agree/denied) message?

please share your opinions.

Comment: You can't do this.  If you need peer to peer communication, you should do this in your application.

It is possible to do this using chaincode and events, but not highly recommended.

Comment: I want to built like this scenario using chaincode, 1st person has to send the money details to 2nd person and then 2nd person has to send a message to agree/denied to 1st person. is it possible?

Comment: Are you assuming a "person" is someone running a "peer"?  That's really not how Fabric works

Comment: person means my application user

Comment: the answer below makes sense

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible inside a chaincode itself.

I don't know what the exact purpose of your need but here an alternative solution :

Plug a websocket inside an API outside the hyperledger fabric network, use the SDK to communicate with the blockchain network.

Then subscribe to one of this event's :

- Block Event's
- Chaincode Event

Here a litle scenario :

A and B are listening for chaincode event (example: a function who write a message in the ledger) in a websocket connection, A is listening for B and B is listening for A

A call an Invoke, writing a message & updating the ledger

B chaincode event trigger, B do some buisness logic inside the websocket connection with the message, and call an Invoke, writing a message & updating the ledger

A chaincode event trigger, A do some buisness...

If you want only real time reaction depending on what happen on the network, websocket is not necessery.
If you has to update for example, a frontend depending on the network event, then choose websocket & event (example: live chat on blockchain)

Hope I answered your question.

Here the documentation of the event's :

[Event's documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/peer_event_services.html)

Comment: In my scenario, 1st person has to send the money details to 2nd person and then 2nd person has to send message to agree/denied to 1st person

Comment: You can do a chaincode that take 3 functions. One to get all the money details concerning an actor, one that write money details and one that aggreed or denied. Then A write money details using function one, B can view the money details that he has to agreed/denied with function two, and agreed / denied with function 3

Comment: do you how to built send messages from one person to another application without using socket, I am new to HF and node.js, please help me.